# Insert unique ipaddress in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have a problem. I want to insert ipaddress and date of visit of each visitors in my database but the ip is inserted every time when I refresh the page or I open a news.
My code: 
NewsController:

```
public function __construct(){
     $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
     $sIpAddress = Visitors_lib::getIp();
     $dDateVisit = time("Y/m/d H:i:s");
     $oVisitor = new \Visitors();
     $bInsert = $oVisitor->addVisitor($sIpAddress,$dDateVisit);
}
```

VisitorsModel:

```
public function addVisitor($sIpAdress,$dDate){
    $oVisitor = new Visitors();
    $oVisitor->ipaddress = $sIpAdress;
    $oVisitor->date = $dDate;
    $oVisitor->save();
}
```

So I want to insert the ip only one. In this situations when I click on the news the ip is inserted in the database, so for an visitor 1 click = 1 insert.

Comment: make that ip field unique in your database

Comment: ip addreses are supposed to be unique in real world, so make it unique in db

Comment: I get an error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10.0.2.2' for key 'ipaddresse'

Comment: you may benefit from using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, this will insert the ip address, but if it already exists, update specific fields of that record

Comment: @DannyHearnah - The OP didn't say anything about wanting to update anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it already exists before entering it:

```
public function addVisitor($ipaddresse, $date)
{
    if ( ! $this->where(compact('ipaddresse'))->first())
    {
        static::create(compact('ipaddresse', 'date'));
    }
}
```